# GCC warning: non-pic addressing form not suitible for pic code

Tags: visual-c++, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

The following code compiles fine in **MSVC**, but **GCC** gives a warning, which really bugs me: **non-pic addressing form not suitible for pic code**.

Can you please tell me the cause of this warning and how to fix it if it really is a potential problem? I am using **-fasm-blocks** compiler option to enable **intel style assembly**, adding **-fpic** argument makes no difference.

```
unsigned short dataMask[] = {0x0ffff, 0x07bef, 0x039e7, 0x018e3, 0x0861, 0x020, 0,0};

void test
{
    _asm
    {
        xor     ecx, ecx // ecx == 0
        //...
        // value in ecx may change
        //...
        mov     bx, [dataMask + ecx * 2]
        //...
    };
}
```

Comment: "PIC code"? Is that like "ATM machine" or "PIN number"? I expected better from the gcc bods :-)

Comment: PIC code means position independent code, it is needed to properly execute instructions in any address space. The code is in a library, so I'm very worried about this warning...

Comment: @Ryan, I think you misunderstood my comment - `PIC` is 'position independent code', `PIC code`, ie, 'position independent code code' is just wrong, like automated teller machine machine or personal identifier number number - serves me right for having a bizarre sense of humour.

Comment: Ah, now even I get it :)

Comment: You should add -fno-pic, because you use absolute addressing, which is, indeed, not suitable for pic

Comment: Thank you, drhirsch! Your answer is the best, too bad it's a comment and I can't accept it :(

Comment: Man, the -fno-pic argument has fixed several other weird issues as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCC is trying to tell you that [dataMask + ecx * 2] isn't a valid addressing mode. This is due to the PIC's nature: it is a RISC, and you're writing RISC code with CISC syntax, not a good idea IMO. Basically, the x86 has a way more complete (and complicated) instruction set, while the PIC's one isn't so extended. I'm quite tired right now, but I hope I was clear ;)